# how to stop thread in onBackPressed or onPause or OnResume

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

Here I'm using location to update longitude and latitude whenever I try to press back button or app is background or any Instance, i want the location_thread to be stopped from running it. Resume it when I switch to current activity.

```
location_thread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.i("TAG",currentThread().getName()+" Running");
                                updateLatLongInfo();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        location_thread.setDaemon(false);
        location_thread.start();
    }

    @Override
//whenever user press a backbutton thread must stoppped
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        location_thread.stop();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Logistic_ReportProblem.this, FPAgentHome.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


    private void updateLatLongInfo() {
        try {
            int locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
            latlongInfo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.latlng_info);
            GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) latlongInfo.getBackground();
            if (locationMode == 0 || locationMode == 1 || locationMode == 2) {
                latlongInfo.setText("Please enable high accuracy in your location settings");
                drawable.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                try {
                    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(context);
                    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
                    android.location.Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                    updateWithNewLocation(location);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);

                    param_latitude = df.format(lat).toString();
                    param_longitude = df.format(lng).toString();

                    // latlongInfo.setText("Latitude :" + Math.round(lat * 1000000.0) / 1000000.0 + " ," + " Longitude :" + Math.round(lng * 1000000.0) / 1000000.0);
                    latlongInfo.setText("Latitude : " + param_latitude + " ," + " Longitude : " + param_longitude);
                    latlongInfo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    drawable.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.toString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: the main problem is that you are using `getLastKnownLocation` for getting updated location ... it is terrible idea ... instead of this you should do this with `locationListener` ... you can find sample code on officiall android guide website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use `Thread.stop()` method its [deprecated and unsafe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Best to way to stop thread is to complete it`s work

Create volatile variable, something like

```
public volatile boolean threadIsStopped;
```

Replace your

```
while (!isInterrupted())
```

to

```
while (!threadIsStopped)
```

And then just make it true

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    threadIsStopped = true;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Logistic_ReportProblem.this, FPAgentHome.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Since your backpress starts another activity and finishes current its better to do such thing:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    threadIsStopped = false;
    //start thread here
} 

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onResume();
    threadIsStopped = true;
}
```

So there`s no need to stop thread in`onBackPressed` at all.

Notice that there is possible delay after `threadIsStopped` is set before thread will be stopped.

About resuming thread - in your case you just create new thread and start it.

Also notice that `onPause` and `onResume` will be called again if you change orientation of your device. Thats why strongly recommended to use `IntentService` for such things.